# Is it possible to get an absolute URI to a local React Native image asset in release mode on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, axios, release, relative-path

I need to post a local image asset to my application's back end and I'm running into issues specifically in release mode on Android (iOS debug/release and Android debug work without issue).

To get the uri of the asset, I just do:

```
const img = require('imagePath');
...
const uri = Image.resolveAssetSource(img).uri;
```

When I use the above as the URI source for images, it works in all cases (even Android release mode).

When I use the above to source a URI to be added to form data for a post API call, it works fine except in Android release mode, where it fails with a generic 500 Network error without ever hitting the back end.

The only difference between these scenarios I can see is that the URIs I'm getting in iOS debug/release and Android debug are all absolute while the one I get in Android release mode is relative.

Is there a way to get an absolute URI instead of a relative one for a local image asset in Android release mode?